# How to fix this count? PHP+HTML the textarea can't add count in name='limit' name='amount'

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my PHP Code

```
   <?php 
    $count = 0;
    $counter = $count++;
    ?>
```

my html

```
<body>
    <h2 style="color:green">GeeksforGeeks</h2>
    <strong> Adding and Deleting Input fields Dynamically</strong>
    <div style="width:40%;">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="row">
                        <div class="input-group m-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger"
                                        id="DeleteRow"
                                        type="button">
                                    <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                                    Delete
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <textarea name="limit[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" type="number" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Code"></textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="amount[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" type="number" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Amount"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 
                    <div id="newinput"></div>
                    <button id="rowAdder" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
                        <span class="bi bi-plus-square-dotted">
                        </span> ADD
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit">test</input>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#rowAdder").click(function () {
            newRowAdd =
                '<div id="row"> <div class="input-group m-3" id="">' +
                '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="DeleteRow" type="button">' +
                '<i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Delete</button> </div>' +
                '<textarea name="limit[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" type="number" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Code"></textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="amount[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" type="number" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Amount"></textarea> </div> </div>';
 
            $('#newinput').append(newRowAdd);
        });
        $("body").on("click", "#DeleteRow", function () {
            $(this).parents("#row").remove();
        })
    </script>
```

i expect if add a `<textarea>` the namefield is counting like.

```
name="limit[0]" name="amount[0]"
name="limit[1]" name="amount[1]"
name="limit[2]" name="amount[2]"
name="limit[3]" name="amount[3]"
```

Comment: Please post the code in the question, in a minimal format. We dont need everything, just where the issue is present.

Comment: Use the edit link https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77122444/edit

Comment: PHP is run on the server, Javascript on the client. `$count++` will be run once when the script is loaded. Why not count in Javascript?

Comment: The way you have it, the value of `$counter` will always be "1" because it is increased from "0" (the value of `$count`)